# Sending Push Notifications using OneSignal to Multiple Users

Tags: node.js, push-notification, onesignal

I have a NodeJS backend application I'm trying to configure to be able to send Push notifications to an IOS frontend application. I want to be able to send notifications to specific users (intend to use PlayerIds to send notifications). I am not sure how to obtain the users playerIds that I want to send.

```
var message = { 
   app_id: "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
   contents: {"en": "English Message"},
   include_player_ids: ["6392d91a-b206-4b7b-a620-cd68e32c3a76","76ece62b-bcfe-468c-8a78-839aeaa8c5fa","8e0f21fa-9a5a-4ae7-a9a6-ca1f24294b86"]
};
sendNotification(message);
```

My question is how can I pull these player_ids dynamically and match them against users in my DB? Thanks!

Onesignal documentation https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification

Comment: Also if theres a better option than using PlayerIds I'd love to hear that as well!

Answer (score 3):

You can set your user id from your DB by calling `setExternalUserId`, example:

```
OneSignal.setExternalUserId("123");
```

You can then use `"filters"` with `include_external_user_ids` on the OneSignal [create notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification) REST API POST call on your server with the tag field to target your users.

Comment: Thanks so much for you response @jkasten! I'm pretty new at Node and development in general so apologies if I'm not asking the best questions :).  So if I have a call like this:


`OneSignal.GetIdsAvailable(IdsAvailable);`


Do you mind providing an example of how you would create a function that would match the ID of a specific user? I'm not exactly sure how it correlates to a specific user I want returned, this seems like it just returns all the ids available.

Comment: @user2019182 You will need to have your own user id and then send both to your server. I have updated my answer with an alternative using tags instead.

Comment: PLEASE NOTE .. As per the new one signal documents: "Do not use tags for setting "user Ids" or sending messages to individual users. Instead, use the External User Id property."

Comment: @tejas.s Thanks for pointing that out!, I updated my answer.